# Sql server Query : Conditional Select columns with top keyword

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

```
DECLARE @mode INT; 

SELECT CASE
        WHEN @mode = 0 
            THEN t.Column1,Count(t.Column2) as Column2 
        ELSE top 1 t.Column1,Count(t.Column2) as Column2 
        END 
FROM Table1 t 
--Where some list of parameters 
Group by t.Column1,t.Column2
```

Please read the above sql statement carefully. I have requirement to evaluate the query by two modes without changing the body of the query ie. From,Where and Group clauses should be written only once and not to replicate them (each one) anywhere in the result query

if @mode = 0 then the above said columns should be returned, and

if @mode <> 0 then the "Top1" of records should be returned

Both select conditions use the same given set list of parameters.
When I run the above query am facing the error `"Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'top'`." because we could not use the top 1 keyword within conditional select statements and select condition's columns must be matched even with their datatypes.

I need to fix the above query without affecting logic of the query.

Comment: `SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Table1 t GROUP BY t.Column1,t.Column2` - that will not work

Comment: `SELECT column1, Count(Column2) FROM table1 Group By column1, column2` wil return column1, 1 for every distinct column1, Column2

Comment: Yes. my intention is reuse the logic (ie. where conditions) in both modes

Comment: @SenthilArumugam: Then you have to put all the data to a temporary table first and the select top 1 or count

Comment: Problably [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378), why you need this? Your query is a nonsense

Comment: this is just my requirement and make Top 1 as optional in the selection list of a query. my above question was modified.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @mode INT;
Set @mode  = 1 --for Min set of records
--Set @mode  = 100 --for Max / full set of records
SELECT TOP (@var) PERCENT * t.Column1 ,Count(t.Column2) AS Column2 FROM Table1 t 
--Where some list of parameters
GROUP BY t.Column1 ,t.Column2
```

Answer (score 3):

```
IF(@mode <= 0)
BEGIN
   Select Column1,Count(t.Column2) as Column2 
   From Table1 t 
   Group by t.Column1,t.Column2
END
Else
BEGIN
   Select top 1 *
   From Table1 t 
END
```

Or create a temporary table and load data using where condition

```
Create Table #Temp (Column1 datetype,Column2 datetype)
Insert Into #Temp (Column1,Column2)
Select Column1,Column2
From Table1 t 
Where condition

  IF(@mode <= 0)
    BEGIN
       Select Column1,Count(t.Column2) as Column2 
       From #Temp t 
       Group by t.Column1,t.Column2
    END
    Else
    BEGIN
       Select top 1 *
       From #Temp t 
    END
```

Comment: How can we include where condition which is common for both conditions without re-writing for each one?

Comment: Good.finding the answer without Temp table and updated my above question.

Answer (score 0):

```
BEGIN
DECLARE @mode INT; 
SET @mode = 0;
IF  @mode <= 0
    SELECT t.Column1,count(t.Column2) as  Column2 from Table_Name t
    GROUP BY t.Column1,t.Column2
ELSE
    SELECT TOP 1 t.Column1,count(t.Column2) as Column2 from Table_Name t
    GROUP BY t.Column1,t.Column2
END
```

Comment: dude..Seems really near to my expectation.but looks like re-writing the logic [Group by and where clauses].